# Order of CSS margin

Tags: html, css, margin

What is order of writing margins in CSS?
For example:

```
div
{
    margin: 20px 40px 30px 50px;
}
```

Which one these represent Margin from top, bottom, left and right?

Comment: It's clearly outlined in the spec. You need to read it sometime.

Comment: This shouldn't be a question.  Googling "css margin" returned this in the first search result.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

Comment: There is a hint on remembering: Its like a clock: starting at 12 and then going clockwise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
margin: top right bottom left //4 parameters 10px 12px 13px 15px
margin: top horizontal bottom //3 parameters 10px 12px 13px, gives left & right same margin of 12px
margin: vertical horizontal //2 parameters 10px 20px, gives 10px for top/bottom and 20px for left/right
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

It goes clockwise from the top. Top -> Right -> Bottom -> Left

Answer (score 0):

Its **clockwise direction** from TOP.

TOP > RIGHT > BOTTOM > LEFT

Answer (score 0):

Its goes from **TOP -> RIGHT -> BOTTOM -> LEFT**

You can check [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/remember-the-order-of-marginpadding-shorthand-with-trouble/) for reference

> The trick is that the first four consonants in the word are the first
>   letters of "Top", "Right", "Bottom" and "Left"

Easy to remember

## TRouBLe

So

```
margin: 20px 40px 30px 50px; // 20px=top 40px=left 30px=bottom 50px=right
```

Answer (score 0):

Top -> Right -> Bottom -> Left

A nice way to remember is TRouBLe.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use any of these methods.

**css**

```
margin : 1px 2px 3px 4px ; // 1=top 2=right 3=bottom 4=left

margin : 1px  2px 3px; // 1=top 2=(left and right) 3=bottom

margin : 1px  2px ; // 1=(top and bottom) 2=(left and right)
```

Comment: Your first example is incorrect - the values are read in a clockwise direction from the top: top, right, bottom, left

Comment: You are right, i just saw it. i guess when i was writing i mirrored it in mind. thank you

Answer (score 0):

CSS Margin works in a clockwise direction.

For example, if I am giving the  following margin to a div which have a class name "marginAll".

`<div class="marginAll"> </div>`
and css as follow

```
.marginAll{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px ;
 }
```

So this code will create a div with a 50px width and height with red color background.
here margin work as **10px from top**, **30px from right**, **10px bottom**, **30px from left**.

Answer (score 0):

Order of CSS margin is,

Top-Right-Bottom-Left